# Spinner OnItemSelectedListener not working properly with 2 spinners in 1 activity

Tags: android, sqlite, spinner

I have been doing coding in android studio with 2 spinners in 1 activity. When I select an Item it doesn't invoke the Listener even if the spinners have different variables.

Below is the relevant code for populating the spinner from the database and also for selecting the value (in loadSYData function)

```
public void loadQtrData() {
    Cursor cursor = myDb.getQtr();
    ArrayList<String> qtrLabel = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> qtrAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_item, qtrLabel);
    qtrAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item);
    spinnerQtrParent.setAdapter(qtrAdapter);
    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
        String label = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("SC_Quarter"));
        qtrLabel.add(label);
    }
}

public void loadSYData(){
    Cursor cursor = myDb.getSY();
    ArrayList<String> syLabel = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> syAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_item, syLabel);
    syAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item);
    spinnerSYParent.setAdapter(syAdapter);
    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
        String label = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("SY"));
        syLabel.add(label);
    }
    spinnerSYParent.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            sy = "Success";
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
}
```

I have also put a toast that will say success just to check if the listener gets invoked. But the toast procedure doesn't execute.

Answer (score 0):

May be your cursor have no data or it is not moving to first position
check this code and see weather your spinner event gets set or not.

```
    public void loadSYData(){
        Cursor cursor = myDb.getSY();
        ArrayList<String> syLabel = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayAdapter<String> syAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_item, syLabel);
        syAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item);
        spinnerSYParent.setAdapter(syAdapter);
        // add this line to move cursor to 1st position.
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            String label = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("SY"));
            syLabel.add(label);
        }
        // Put debug point or print some thing here to confirm
        spinnerSYParent.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                sy = "Success";
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I have tried and added "Toast.makeText(this, "After population", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);" the toast didn't execute.

Comment: Have added my code ? Then there must be some error. check log

Comment: W/InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.

Comment: Yes i have added moveToFirst()

Comment: Add error log and db code also. b'z i think issue is in db code

Comment: oh. I forgot to show the toast. the toast actually executes. the listener is the only one that is not working